# Expanding one field while others are collapsed in blackberry java

Tags: java, eclipse, blackberry

I am developing an app in which i am adding and deleting fields based on setting flag to true or false.but what i am trying to do is if i click on field that particular field should expand while others are collapsed(even if it is expanded)
i googled it but i didnt get solution please help me i am new to blackberry java

i have used below code

```
 public final class MyScreen extends MainScreen implements 
FieldChangeListener
{
    /**
     * Creates a new MyScreen object
     */
    private VerticalFieldManager main_manager;
    private HorizontalFieldManager parentNodes;
    private LabelField parent_lables[];
    private Bitmap bitmap,upbitmap;
    private BitmapField bitmap_field[];
    private VerticalFieldManager submanager[];
    private int sizeOfParentNodes=3;
    private int sizeOfChildNodes=5;
    private static boolean flag[];

    public MyScreen()
    {        
        // Set the displayed title of the screen       
        bitmap=Bitmap.getBitmapResource("arrow.png");
        upbitmap=Bitmap.getBitmapResource("uparrow.png");
        main_manager=new  
     VerticalFieldManager(Manager.VERTICAL_SCROLL|VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR){
            protected void sublayout(int maxWidth, int maxHeight) {
                super.sublayout(Display.getWidth(), Display.getHeight());
                setExtent(Display.getWidth(), Display.getHeight());
            };
        };
        parent_lables=new LabelField[sizeOfParentNodes];
        flag=new boolean[sizeOfParentNodes];
        submanager=new VerticalFieldManager[sizeOfParentNodes];
        bitmap_field=new BitmapField[sizeOfParentNodes];
        for(int i=0;i<sizeOfParentNodes;i++)
        {
            submanager[i]=new VerticalFieldManager();
            updateGUI(i);
            main_manager.add(submanager[i]);
        }
        add(main_manager);
    }

    public void fieldChanged(Field field, int context) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        synchronized (UiApplication.getEventLock()) {
            for(int i=0;i<sizeOfParentNodes;i++)
            {   if(field==parent_lables[i])
                {
                    if(flag[i]==true){
                        flag[i]=false;
                        submanager[i].deleteAll();
                        updateGUI(i);
                        parent_lables[i].setFocus();
                    }else{
                        flag[i]=true;
                        bitmap_field[i].setBitmap(upbitmap);

                        submanager[i].invalidate();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void updateGUI(int index)
    {
        parentNodes=new HorizontalFieldManager(USE_ALL_WIDTH);
        bitmap_field[index]=new BitmapField(bitmap);

        parentNodes.add(bitmap_field[index]);
        parent_lables[index]=new LabelField("Day"+index,Field.FOCUSABLE){
            protected boolean navigationClick(int status, int time) {
                fieldChangeNotify(1);
                return true;
            };
        };
        parentNodes.add(parent_lables[index]);
        parent_lables[index].setChangeListener(this);
        submanager[index].add(parentNodes);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I knocked this together, and will likely need some tweaks by you to get it exactly how you want it, but it should be something you can work from. Assuming I've understood your question correctly.

You'll need to create a base field, a helper able to manage a list of them, and a callback. The fact that you need a base field is the biggest downfall, because it immediately excludes all other widgets you have, as they need to be made from scratch with the `paint` method. You can use a `VerticalFieldManager` instead of field by extending `VerticalFieldManager` instead of `Field`.

On to the java classes.
My `CollapsableField.java` looks as follows:

```
public abstract class CollapsableField extends Field
{
    // We make use of a different listener than the FieldChangeListener, since you can only attach one and we will most likely want to do so, we can't "occupy" the listener.
    private CollapseListener listener;
    private boolean collapsed;
    protected int collapsedWidth;
    protected int collapsedHeight;

    public CollapsableField()
    {
        collapsed = true;

        // Field is completely collapsed by default
        collapsedWidth = 0;
        collapsedHeight = 0;
    }

    public void setCollapseListener(CollapseListener listener)
    {
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    public final boolean isCollapsed()
    {
        return collapsed;
    }

    public final void collapse()
    {
        this.collapsed = true;
        if (listener != null)
        {
            listener.onCollapse(this);
        }
        fieldChangeNotify(0); // Notify that the field has changed, so that attached field change listeners will fire
        updateLayout(); // re-call layout
    }

    public final void expand()
    {
        this.collapsed = false;
        if (listener != null)
        {
            listener.onExpand(this);
        }
        fieldChangeNotify(0); // Notify that the field has changed, so that attached field change listeners will fire
        updateLayout(); // re-call layout
    }

    protected void layout(int width, int height)
    {
        if (collapsed)
        {
            // Set dimensions to collapsed
            setExtent(collapsedWidth, collapsedHeight);
        }
        else
        {
            // Set dimensions to what the extending class specified
            setExtent(width, height);
        }
    }

    protected final void paint(Graphics graphics)
    {
        if (collapsed)
        {
            paintCollapsed(graphics);
        }
        else
        {
            paintExpanded(graphics);
        }
    }

    protected abstract void paintCollapsed(Graphics graphics);

    protected abstract void paintExpanded(Graphics graphics);
}
```

The Group then takes a list of these, applies a listener to each field as it's added. When a field signals that it has expanded, the group will tell all other fields to collapse themselves.
CollapsableGroup.java:

```
public class CollapsableGroup
{
    private Vector fields;
    private CollapseListener listener;

    public CollapsableGroup()
    {
        fields = new Vector();

        listener = new CollapseListener()
        {
            public void onExpand(CollapsableField source)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < fields.size(); i++)
                {
                    CollapsableField field = (CollapsableField) fields.elementAt(i);
                    if ((!field.isCollapsed()) && (field != source))
                    {
                        field.collapse();
                    }
                }
            }

            public void onCollapse(CollapsableField source)
            {
                // Don't need to handle this. Method is here just for completeness
            }
        };
    }

    public void add(CollapsableField field)
    {
        field.setCollapseListener(listener);
        fields.addElement(field);
    }

    public void remove(CollapsableField field)
    {
        field.setCollapseListener(null);
        fields.removeElement(field);
    }

    /**
     * Returns the currently expanded field. Returns <b>null</b> if all fields are collapsed.
     * 
     * @return
     */
    public CollapsableField getExpandedField()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < fields.size(); i++)
        {
            CollapsableField field = (CollapsableField) fields.elementAt(i);
            if (!field.isCollapsed())
            {
                return field;
            }
        }

        return null;
    }

    public void expand(CollapsableField field)
    {
        field.expand(); // Listeners should take care of the rest
    }

    public void collapseAll()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < fields.size(); i++)
        {
            CollapsableField field = (CollapsableField) fields.elementAt(i);
            if (!field.isCollapsed())
            {
                field.collapse();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And finally the listener interface.
CollapseListener.java:

```
interface CollapseListener
{
    public void onExpand(CollapsableField source);

    public void onCollapse(CollapsableField source);
}
```

Those three classes should be all that you need. The classes that follow are my example/test classes.
TestLabel.java is an example of an extended class:

```
public class TestLabel extends CollapsableField
{
    private String text;
    private String collapsedText;

    public TestLabel(String text, String collapsedText)
    {
        this.text = text;
        this.collapsedText = collapsedText;

        // Tells the layout method to collapse to the size of this text
        collapsedWidth = getFont().getAdvance(collapsedText);
        collapsedHeight = getFont().getHeight();
    }

    public int getPreferredWidth()
    {
        return getFont().getAdvance(text);
    }

    public int getPreferredHeight()
    {
        return getFont().getHeight();
    }

    protected void layout(int width, int height)
    {
        super.layout(getPreferredWidth(), getPreferredHeight());
    }

    protected void paintCollapsed(Graphics graphics)
    {
        // Paints only the collapsedText
        graphics.drawText(collapsedText, 0, 0);
    }

    protected void paintExpanded(Graphics graphics)
    {
        // Paints the full Text
        graphics.drawText(text, 0, 0);
    }

    protected boolean touchEvent(TouchEvent message)
    {
        // Toggle on mouse press
        if (message.getEvent() == TouchEvent.CLICK)
        {
            if (isCollapsed())
            {
                expand();
            }
            else
            {
                collapse();
            }

            return true;
        }
        return super.touchEvent(message);
    }
}
```

The following screen contains some of the fields to show that both the widgets themselves and the group can manipulate the fields.
MyScreen.java:

```
public final class MyScreen extends MainScreen
{
    public MyScreen()
    {
        // Set the displayed title of the screen
        setTitle("MyTitle");

        final CollapsableGroup group = new CollapsableGroup();

        final TestLabel label1 = new TestLabel("Label1", "L1");
        label1.setBackground(BackgroundFactory.createSolidBackground(0x999999));
        group.add(label1);

        final TestLabel label2 = new TestLabel("Label2", "L2");
        label2.setBackground(BackgroundFactory.createSolidBackground(0xBBBBBB));
        group.add(label2);

        final TestLabel label3 = new TestLabel("Label3", "L3");
        label3.setBackground(BackgroundFactory.createSolidBackground(0xDDDDDD));
        group.add(label3);

        ButtonField collapseAll = new ButtonField("Collapse All")
        {
            protected boolean navigationClick(int status, int time)
            {
                group.collapseAll();
                return true;
            }
        };
        add(collapseAll);

        ButtonField expand1 = new ButtonField("Expand1")
        {
            protected boolean navigationClick(int status, int time)
            {
                group.expand(label1);
                return true;
            }
        };
        add(expand1);

        ButtonField expand2 = new ButtonField("Expand2")
        {
            protected boolean navigationClick(int status, int time)
            {
                group.expand(label2);
                return true;
            }
        };
        add(expand2);

        ButtonField expand3 = new ButtonField("Expand3")
        {
            protected boolean navigationClick(int status, int time)
            {
                group.expand(label3);
                return true;
            }
        };
        add(expand3);

        add(label1);
        add(label2);
        add(label3);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can i get your skypeid Please.

Comment: I don't want to post something like that to the public. If you'd like, we can create a chat room on SO.